# Download file from public dropbox link to server using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, dropbox

Is there any way to download file from anyones dropbox via public link and save it on my server with node js? I need a way without any type of authentication. For example, how can i download a file from given link like this `https://www.dropbox.com/s/dr1cit55idwi1m0/english_buisness_message.txt?dl=0`

Comment: You could use their API. 
https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/04/a-preview-of-the-new-dropbox-api-v2/

Comment: @crellee it assumes authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case next code worked correctly:

```
    var link = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/dr1cit55idwi1m0/english_buisness_message.txt?dl=0"
    var firstPart = link.split("=")[0];
    link = firstPart + '=1';
    var myFile = request(link).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./dist/testtest.txt'));
    myFile.write(resFull.data);
    myFile.end(() => {
        /..here is callback function../
     })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to download something that requires authentication then you must do the authentication in your project as well. - There is no way around.

If the link is public then you could try something like this (notice that the last 0 in the url is changed to 1):

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream("english_buisness_message.txt");
var request = http.get("https://www.dropbox.com/s/dr1cit55idwi1m0/english_buisness_message.txt?dl=1", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

Comment: I've tried. But it saves an empty file. (BTW I'm using 'axios' instead 'http')

Comment: I think I found it. Try to edit the last 0 in the URL to a 1 instead, like i have in the code above

Comment: so https://www.dropbox.com/s/dr1cit55idwi1m0/english_buisness_message.txt?dl=1 instead of ...dl=0

Comment: the same - empty file

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox response isn't the file itself, but a redirect to a final URL where the file really is, so to avoid getting an empty file you must **follow the redirect** *and then* download the file. A simple way to do that with the `https` library would be:

```
    var https = require('https');
    var fs = require('fs');

    // (...)

    var myDropboxURL = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/dr1cit55idwi1m0/english_buisness_message.txt?dl=1';
    var file = fs.createWriteStream('path/to/the/dest/file');

    var request = (url) => {
      https.get(url, (response) => {
        if (response.statusCode == 302) { // it's a redirect!
          request(response.headers.location);
        } else {
          response.pipe(fp);
          file.on('finish', () => {
            file.close(() => {
              // You may do something here
            });
          });
        }
      }).on('error', (err) => {
        // Do something if the request fails
      });

    // Here we start the request
    request(myDropboxURL);
```

As seen in other answers, first you should also change the query string so `dl` is `1` (so you get the file instead of Dropbox's web interface).